# Why some users answer questions in comments?

Tags: support, questions, comments

I would like to know why some users answer questions in comments.

Is there any official reason for it?

Comment: I do that when I am lazy to follow up if the Original Poster gets another doubt after solving his current problem. :P

Comment: No reason. Probably too broad/duplicate for "why part". (This is an example of answer in comment, because really "no" is neither acceptable answer on SO nor will be considered as possibility by most posters).

Comment: Writing a good answer takes more time than writing a simple comment.

Comment: I answer a question in a comment when I feel 1 one line will suffice, and do not feel like explaining why the 1 line is significant when it is already explained in 2^20 other places

Comment: we should may be then get a small bounty from comments upvote

Comment: I'll do it if I think the question is going to be eventually closed, but still want to help the op out. If the question is close worthy I don't want my (potentially upvoted) answer preventing its removal.

Comment: Because we want to.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> *"Is there any official reason for that ?"*

No, not that I'm aware of one.

Most probably comments were posted instead of answers by users, because they're either

- not completely sure about, if posting these as an answer, would finally solve the problem asked.
- the question was trivial, asking for an off site resource, or for other *off-topic* issue and doesn't deserve an answer, but a helpful comment.

I'm hitting this situation often myself, when I primarily down-/close-vote for an unclear question or such and give more hints rather in comments.

It's actually sometimes a bit hard to *triage* out, if your comment actually answers the question, thus you'll find answers in comments.

If you're really sure the comment answers the question, you should leave a comment addressed to the commenter to turn their comment into an answer.

Comment: thank you for taking time to clarify that

Comment: Yeah.  It's not uncommon to spot a problem with posted code that, while clearly something that should be fixed, may, or may not, actually fix the OP's issue.  Without a fix/test with the OP's environment, (which is often lengthy and/or impossible for anyone except the OP), I can't tell. So, comment:)